# Group values: CASE text, ELSE field value

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, group-by, case

I have a `ROAD` table:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | ROAD_CLASS |
+----+------------+
|  1 | ARTERIAL A |
|  2 | ARTERIAL B |
|  3 | ARTERIAL B |
|  4 | ARTERIAL C |
|  5 | ARTERIAL C |
|  6 | ARTERIAL C |
|  7 | COLLECTOR  |
|  8 | COLLECTOR  |
|  9 | LOCAL      |
| 10 | LOCAL      |
+----+------------+
```

The data type for the `ROAD_CLASS` field is `NVARCHAR2`.

I would like to create a view that groups all arterial roads in to a single `ARTERIAL` category, but leaves the other road classes as-is:

```
+------------+
| ROAD_CLASS |
+------------+
| ARTERIAL   |
| COLLECTOR  |
| LOCAL      |
+------------+
```

How can I do this?

**What I've tried:**

I've successfully done part of it:

```
SELECT
      (CASE 
          WHEN ROAD_CLASS = 'ARTERIAL A' THEN 'ARTERIAL'
          WHEN ROAD_CLASS = 'ARTERIAL B' THEN 'ARTERIAL'
          WHEN ROAD_CLASS = 'ARTERIAL C' THEN 'ARTERIAL'
          --ELSE ROAD_CLASS
      END) AS ROAD_CLASS_GROUPED
FROM
    USER.ROAD
GROUP BY
      CASE 
          WHEN ROAD_CLASS = 'ARTERIAL A' THEN 'ARTERIAL'
          WHEN ROAD_CLASS = 'ARTERIAL B' THEN 'ARTERIAL'
          WHEN ROAD_CLASS = 'ARTERIAL C' THEN 'ARTERIAL'
      END

+--------------------+
| ROAD_CLASS_GROUPED |
+--------------------+
| null               |
| ARTERIAL           |
+--------------------+
```

However, instead of the other road classes being output as `null`, I'd like to get their field values (`COLLECTOR` and `LOCAL`).

When I try adding `ELSE ROAD_CLASS` to the CASE statement (as demonstrated in the SQL comment) I get an `ORA-12704: character set mismatch` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about ...

```
select distinct 
   (case
       when road_class in('ARTERIAL A','ARTERIAL B','ARTERIAL C') then n'ARTERIAL'
       else road_class
     end ) as ROAD_CLASS_GROUPED
from user.road;
```

Due to the fact that the datatype of the column road_class is NVARCHAR, we need to write a  N  or  n  in front of the string literal 'ARTERIAL' in order to prevent the error message. (see also: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218 )

Comment: @Wilson: done.  I am new here.  Where are all the other comments gone?

Comment: Thanks! I put in a flag: `Can the comments be cleaned up by a moderator? The problem has been solved, via a discussion in the comments. And the result has been put in the question/answer. I don't believe the comments are of value anymore.`

Comment: Phew!  I thought I'd deleted them inadvertently (and thereby cheesing off a few fellow users).  Thanks for letting me know!